# Which min role to install first?

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, minrole

I'll be installing min roles on 4 servers (probably more in the future). Does it matter which min role I install first?

I found [description](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt667910%28v=office.16%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) of the roles, I found some info about their [management](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt743705%28v=office.16%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), and apparently by default [CA runs in all the roles](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/196371/2016-farm-central-administration-service-running-in-all-min-role-servers).

Are there any best practices/your own suggestions or it doesn't matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would install the CA server first. That's mean the server which is going to Host the Central admin web site, I will run the config wizard over there and configure the MinRole( which ever you want i.e custom, WFE, app etc).

Rest you can do in any order.